# Return <list> values from method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I need to get all the appointments from my table for a particular patient, for this I tried like,

```
public List<Appoinment> GetAppoinments()         //here Appointment is a class.
    {
        List<Appoinment> appointments = null;

        foreach (DataObject.Appointment appointment in
                   dataEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.PATIENTID == PatientId))
        {

        }

        return appointments;
    }
```

in my Appointment class and table, I've fields like PatientId, doctorid, appointment date, like this,

here, within the foreach loop I tried like,

```
appointments.add(appointment);
```

its thorwing error, it can't convert automatically from database table appointments to class appointments, right.

I dunno how to do this, can anyone help me out here, thanks in advance

Comment: You should do `appointements.Add(new Appointment {ParientId = ..., OtherStuff = ...})`, according to the current appointment you're iterating.

Comment: Also might want to initialize the null list before adding elements to it!

Comment: You should maybe show us the `Appointment` classes' interfaces. It's hard to help without them.

Comment: thanks, I just tried Craig's way, its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public List<Appointment> GetAppointments()      
{
    return dataEntities.Appointments
                       .Where(a => a.PATIENTID == PatientId)
                       .Select(a => new OtherNamespace.Appointment 
                                    {
                                        Id = a.Id,
                                        Name = a.Name,
                                        // etc.
                                    })
                       .ToList();
}
```

Comment: am gettin error like, cannot convert int? to int, like this, y

Comment: Sure. If you have a property `int Foo` on one type and `int? Foo` on another type, then you must convert, e.g. `Foo = a.Foo.HasValue ? a.Foo.Value : 0,`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like :

```
dataEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.PATIENTID == PatientId)
  .Select (new Appoinment { ... set values from DB element });
```

Comment: and yes Convert it to a List.

Comment: its showing error like,cannot implicitely convert from database appointment to business object appointment

Answer (score 1):

You sloud conver the Data.Appointment to Your.Appointment.

You could do somthing like this.

```
My.Appoint resultAppointment = new My.Appointment();
resultAppointment.Id = dataAppointment.Id
```

But the better approach is to apply a projection over the data apointments. The generated sql query will get only the necesary fields

```
public List<Appoinment> GetAppoinments()         //here Appointment is a class.
    {
        return dataEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.PATIENTID == PatientId))
                                        .Select(a => new Appointment() { Prop1 = a.Prop1})
                                        .ToList();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the solution above....however, 
If you have to write this sort of mapping code often... i.e. code to copy properties of one object into another, then you could consider using Automapper

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: No, don't use AutoMapper. It's *useless* for `IQueryable<T>`